# excel add in to save internal data?

Tags: excel, ms-office, office-automation, office-addins

I am new to writing excel add-in (in C#) and trying to figure out the right way to save some internal data structures so I can restore the state the next time file is opened.  I can convert data in xml or base64 strings if it makes things easier.  I don't want to maintain a separate file and would like to embed this information inside excel worksheet.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: "don't know know how to hide this from the user of your addin". 

i think this is it, I guess I can write data out into a given cell, but definitely don't want the user to see it or be able to manipulate this data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a cell in an invisible sheet (you can name it, for example, "internal data sheet") for storing the information. Excel sheets have a `Visible` property which can be set programmatically to `xlVeryHidden' which means it can only be made visible again by a program. Here you find some more information:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/142530/en-us